# Scrollbar in DialogInput

Tags: text, dialog-window

Writing:

```
DialogInput[DialogNotebook[
                                                  {Style[Row[{

      Style["                   Struttura2D",
       FontColor -> Red,
       FontFamily -> "Consolas",
       FontSize -> 16,
       FontWeight -> "Bold"],

      Text[
       Style["SISTEMA DI RIFERIMENTO GLOBALE: asse delle x di \
direzione orizzontale che 
        punta verso destra, asse delle y di direzione verticale che \
punta verso l'alto, asse 
        delle z ortogonale al piano <x,y> che individua in esso \
rotazioni positive se in sen-
        so antiorario.", LineIndent -> 0, TextAlignment -> Left]]

                                            }],
                                                FontFamily -> "Times"],
                                                 Style[DefaultButton[],

    TextAlignment -> Center]},

  Background -> LightBlue,
                                                  Magnification -> 1.5,

  ShowStringCharacters -> False],

 WindowSize -> {700, 200}]
```

I get:

[image]

where it is evident that the window is not high enough.

The easiest method is clearly to increase the height, but if for some needs I could not increase the height and would like to introduce a vertical scrollbar would be possible?

I tried to look but I did not find anything. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to search documentation for 'scrollbars' and related keywords? See `WindowElements` for notebooks or `Scrollbars` for `Pane`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the closest I can get to what I think you want.

In Mathematica, the way to add a scrollbar to a GUI element such as a window is to use `Pane` which allows scrollbar and resize area widgets to be specified as appearance elements.

```
DialogInput[
  DialogNotebook[
    Pane[
      Column[
        {Style["Struttura2D", FontColor -> Red, FontFamily -> "Consolas", 
           FontSize -> 16, FontWeight -> "Bold"],
         Pane[
           Style["SISTEMA DI RIFERIMENTO GLOBALE: asse delle x di \
direzione orizzontale che punta verso destra, asse delle y di \
direzione verticale che punta verso l'alto, asse delle z ortogonale \
al piano <x,y> che individua in esso rotazioni positive se in senso \
antiorario.",
             LineIndent -> 0, TextAlignment -> Left, FontFamily -> "Times"]],
         DefaultButton[]}, 
        Alignment -> {Center, Center}],
      Scrollbars -> {False, True},
      ImageSize -> {200, 100}],
    Background -> LightBlue,
    Magnification -> 1.5,
    ShowStringCharacters -> False]]
```

The dialog comes up looking like this

[image: initial]

It can be scrolled up to reveal the button

[image: scrolled]

or it can be resized to reveal it.

[image: resized]